# Sql query performance is low

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I would like to optimize my sql query. When I put a lot of data in the **investors_diversificacao** table it gets very slow and doesn't load. But with little data in the **investors_diversificacao** table it can load the data.

I would like help to optimize query response time.

sql query:

```
SELECT investors_positivador.cod_cliente, investors_saldo_financeiro.nome_cliente, investors_base_assessores.squad, investors_base_assessores.nome_investor, investors_saldo_financeiro.saldo_d0, 
                  SUM(CASE WHEN investors_posicao_geral.vencimento <= @vencimento THEN investors_posicao_geral.financeiro ELSE 0 END) AS vencimentos_ate_data, 
                  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN investors_diversificacao.produto = 'Fundos' THEN investors_diversificacao.net / 6 ELSE 0 END), 2) AS fundos_ate_data, investors_guia_fundos.liquidez_total, investors_positivador.contatar_liquidity_map, 
                  investors_positivador.id, investors_posicao_geral.vencimento, investors_base_assessores.nome_assessor
FROM     investors_positivador 
    INNER JOIN investors_saldo_financeiro ON cod_cliente = investors_saldo_financeiro.cod_cliente 
    INNER JOIN investors_base_assessores ON cod_assessor = investors_base_assessores.cod_assessor 
    INNER JOIN investors_posicao_geral ON investors_positivador.cod_cliente = investors_posicao_geral.cod_cliente 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN investors_diversificacao ON investors_positivador.cod_cliente = investors_diversificacao.cod_cliente 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN investors_guia_fundos ON investors_diversificacao.cnpj = investors_guia_fundos.cnpj
WHERE (investors_base_assessores.nome_investor = @investor_nome) AND (investors_saldo_financeiro.saldo_d0 > 0) 
   OR (investors_base_assessores.nome_investor = @investor_nome) AND (investors_posicao_geral.financeiro > 0) 
   OR (investors_base_assessores.nome_investor = @investor_nome) AND (investors_diversificacao.net > 0)
GROUP BY investors_positivador.cod_cliente
```

Comment: Your `where` criteria logic is ambiguous - bracketing individual clauses serves no purpose, I suspect you need to logcically group your and/or boolean expressions.

Comment: Your query is invalid. So rather than worrying about its performance, you should worry about getting it right. You are obviously in MySQLs notorious cheat mode, for otherwise you'd have gotten a syntax error as you should have. Make sure to `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` to get out of that harmful cheat mode. Look at your query. You group by client, but you select columns from various tables. Do all these tables have only one row per client? I doubt that.

Comment: Please tell us for all tables what their unique keys are. Is `cod_cliente` unique in `investors_positivador` for instance? And which of the two tables `investors_positivador` or `investors_saldo_financeiro` contains the column `cod_assessor`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: The indention of the ORs is confusing. It wasn't there in the original request and they suggest a different logic then actually is in the query and what the OP may want. After all the where clause is on `(name match and saldo > 0) or (name match and finance > 0) or (name match and net > 0)` which makes more sense to be (though it can be simplified of course). I think that parentheses may make this clearer, but they are not needed. Unless the OP really wants a different logic.

Comment: @The Impaler: This is not true. `AND` has precedence over `OR`, so the `WJHERE` clause is actually `where iba..nome_investor = @investor_nome AND (isf..saldo_d0 > 0 OR ipg..financeiro > 0 OR id..net > 0)`. This doesn't turn the outer joins to inner joins. Don't let RiggsFolly's edit with the wrong indention`s of `AND` and `OR` confuse you.

Comment: I've edited the request now and corrected the wrong indentions. It was obviously confusing readers. It is not the `WHERE` clause which renders the query invalid. I admit that for all the superfluous parentheses and without them where we'd expect them to be we don't know whether this `WHERE` clause really is what Eric intended it to be. But it looks rather likely and my indention at least matches the clause's actual progression.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) to learn what information we need to help you with query performance. Then please ask another question if you still need help.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these indexes may help:

```
investors_positivador:       INDEX(cod_cliente,  contatar_liquidity_map, id)
investors_saldo_financeiro:  INDEX(cod_cliente, saldo_d0,  nome_cliente)
investors_base_assessores:   INDEX(nome_investor, cod_assessor,  squad, nome_assessor)
investors_posicao_geral:     INDEX(cod_cliente, financeiro,  vencimento)
investors_diversificacao:    INDEX(cod_cliente, net,  produto, cnpj)
investors_guia_fundos:       INDEX(cnpj,  liquidez_total)
```

Are you sure you want that `WHERE` clause?  All the `ORs` are irrelevant, and Riggs' version simplifies to just

```
WHERE  investors_base_assessores.nome_investor = @investor_nome
  AND  investors_diversificacao.net > 0
```

Don't round before summing; you will get extra rounding errors:

```
ROUND(SUM(IF(investors_diversificacao.produto = 'Fundos',
             investors_diversificacao.net, 0
            )
         ) / 6     -- divide after summing and before rounding
  , 2) AS fundos_ate_data
```

Comment: It seems you fell victim to RiggsFolly's request edit, too. They added confusing indentions to the `WHERE` clause that didn't match the clause's progression, as `AND` has precedence over `OR`, not vice versa. I've corrected this now in the request. Look at it again; the `WHERE` clause can be simplified, but the `ORs` aren't irrelevant at all.